# Why is catching "Exception" not ambiguous when I have System.Exception and MyNamespace.Exception?

Tags: c#

In my C# code, I have access to a `MyNamespace.Exception` as well as a `System.Exception`. When I want to catch one of those exceptions, ideally I'd fully qualify which one I want to catch or use aliasing to make it clear. However, I'm concerned that it's all to easy to just type `catch(Exception)`. I assumed that the compiler would flag this up as an ambiguous name, however it doesn't. It always assumes I'm want a `MyNamespace.Exception` which clearly leaves a hole for many exceptions to miss the catch if I meant to use a `System.Exception`. This is not just a problem with `Exception`, I also have exceptions such as `MyNamespace.ArgumentException`.

So my question is why does the compiler not complain about an ambiguous exception type? Also, how would you go about protecting against this problem?

Comment: **Exterminate that class!**  (or at least rename it)

Comment: Silly question: Is the `System` namespace in the usings of the source file in question? Also, does the compiler complain if, in the same source file, you do `Exception test = new Exception()`? ... and what @SLaks said; your best bet is to rename them to be more specific so this isn't an issue at all. (it's a pain to deal with the ambiguities when they do occur, and makes it very difficult to read the code)

Comment: Post a complete class snippet with namespaces at the top

Comment: @Andrew, @Aliostad: `static void Main() { Console.WriteLine(Exception.V); } class Exception { public static int V = 42; }`

Comment: Read this blogpost: It explains the problem of having multiple exceptions with the same name: http://bit.ly/fEzlRD.

Comment: @Steven: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @SLaks, I quote: "What they didn’t realize that about 75% of the time they actually caught the real System.ApplicationException instead of their own business layer exception [named ApplicationException].".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why does the compiler not complain about an ambiguous exception type?

Probably because it is not ambiguous the way you've stated it. If you said:

```
using MyNamespace;
using System;
class P 
{
    void M()
    {
        try { ... } catch(Exception) { ... }
```

then it would be ambiguous because it is not clear which "using" directive is the relevant one; both could work.

If you said

```
using System;
namespace MyNamespace
{
  class P 
  {
    void M()
    {
      try { ... } catch(Exception) { ... }
```

Then it is not ambiguous; stuff in the current namespace takes priority over stuff imported by a using directive.

> how would you go about protecting against this problem?

I would not get into the situation in the first place. Naming your types the same as common system types is confusing, dangerous and contrary to good design principles.

Answer (score 2):

Types in the current namespace have priority over other types.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens has to do with the way the C# compiler resolves names.  In short it will prefer a name which exists in the current namespace to one in a namespace which is imported.

The first step to preventing this problem is to not define types which have the same name as types in the `System` namespace.  Doing this will only lead you to potential ambiguous names (to the developer).  Instead choose unambiguous names like `MyException` or `MyArgumentException`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not name my exception `Exception`.  Instead name it something else (like `myException`).

Comment: This does not answer the question.